# How to perform deep copy at ADTs in C?

Tags: c

Recently, I am writing some Abstract Data Types (ADTs) for Queue in C Language.
But I found a problem for ADT in C:

> How can I pass the type of data in C?

For example, in C++ I can use the template to pass type:

```
 std::queue< struct mySt > myQ;
```

That template will pass "struct mySt" type to create myQ.
But how to do this in C?
All I know is to create a generic pointer pushing the data of "struct mySt" like below:

```
void enq(void *dataPtr);
```

and pop it using casting like below:

```
struct mySt *a = (struct mySt *) deq()
```

That seems work in C, but how can I perform "deep copy" action? I mean creating a new memory space for the content of the pointer dataPtr rather than just points it?
Except using Macro or Function pointer to solve this, is there other better way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to do it in C.  The C++ code relies on constructors (the copy constructor) to implement the copy, which is necessary because you can't tell a priori whether there are pointers in the class or allocated memory that need to be altered when an independent copy of the structure is made.

If you are going to copy the structures in a C ADT, then at a bare minimum you will need to specify the size of the structure to be copied as part of the interface.  However, you really need a copy function that knows how to deal with the pointers in a copy of the structure.

Passing pointers around is simpler; it is clear that the object that is pointed at continues to exist unmodified by the fact that its pointer is now stored in a list.